# Direct access to a doc in an documen query array returns undefined outside of the onSnapshot() block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to pass the result of the queried documents (which is an array) outside of the function. However, accessing this array outside of the onSnapshot function yields undefined.

I have spent a whole day on this trying various things but can't figure it out.

```
export const getComments = (taskId) => {
    const comments = [] // i want to return this array once it is filled wit documents

    const dbRef = db.collection('tasks').doc(taskId).collection('comments') // comments is a subcollection of each task document
    dbRef.onSnapshot(
        (querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                comments.push(doc.data()) //each doc.data() is an object that gets pushed to the comments array. Lets say that the 1st doc.data() is {userId: 'xyz', user: 'Kiu', comment: 'this is my 1st stack overflow question'}
            })
            console.log('value for comments[0] inside onSnapshot')
            console.log(comments[0]) //sucessfully display the 1st object in the array as {userId: 'xyz', user: 'Kiu', comment: 'this is my 1st stack overflow question'}
        },
        (error) => {
            throw new Error(error.message)
        }
    )
    console.log('value for comments[0] outside onSnapshot')
    console.log(comments[0]) // this is undefined for some reason????

    console.log('value for the whole comments array outside onSnapshot')
    console.log(comments) // this does actually show the whole array, however any method used here (i.e. forEach(), map() ) returns undefined. ????

    return comments
}
```

When calling getComments(taskId) in App.js the console.log() result is not what I expect. Can somebody please help this newbie?

--update#1 : I read elsewhere on stack overflow that onSnapshot is to activate a listener. Listeners are not to be used in an asynchronous fashion , as listeners stay 'on' until unsubscribed. So i don't think using async and await will work for this one. I think this is where I read it. See the bottom of this discussion: [What is the right way to cancel all async/await tasks within an useEffect hook to prevent memory leaks in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562474/what-is-the-right-way-to-cancel-all-async-await-tasks-within-an-useeffect-hook-t)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with doing asynchronous calls(?). I read elsewhere to not use ```onSnapshot() ``` with ```await```: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64521755/firestore-onsnapshot-or-async-await-issue-or-both and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562474/what-is-the-right-way-to-cancel-all-async-await-tasks-within-an-useeffect-hook-t

Comment: But what is your purpose of the function? Do you want to create listener or just retrieve data from Firestore?

Comment: @vitooh I would like to return an array of objects (which each contains info of a comment) to a react component for rendering a list of the comments. I am using onSnapshot so that other authorized users can view the comments when even a new one is added.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are returning (and accessing) the `comments` array outside of the `onSnapshot()` call.

According to [the docs for listening to collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection), you should be listening to/modifying/returning/etc. the `comments` array from within the `onSnapshot()` block:

```js
export const getComments = (taskId) => {
  const comments = [];

  const dbRef = db.collection("tasks").doc(taskId).collection("comments");
  dbRef.onSnapshot(
    (querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        comments.push(doc.data());
      });
      console.log("value for comments[0] inside onSnapshot");
      console.log(comments[0]);
      return comments; // or comments.map(), comments.forEach(), etc.
    },
    (error) => {
      throw new Error(error.message);
    }
  );
};
```

Your `useEffect` hook in `App.js` should follow the `unsubscribe` pattern as described in the [React docs for Effects with Cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).

Comment: I read multiple times the firebase docs that you linked to. I just didn't see an explicit explanation that I can't passed the ```onSnapshot()``` results. This is likely my current shallow understanding of js and listeners. ALSO yes, I will proceed to use the useEffect hook with cleanup with onSnapshot. I read a much of blogs on this yesterday, and it seems that this is the way to go to pass on the onSnapshot results.

Comment: Your only problem was that you were handling `comments` from outside the scope of the `onSnapshot()`. `comments` (or whatever you're doing with them) need to be returned from *inside* the function passed to `onSnapshot()`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a bunch of forums, and the response above from @kamillamagna, I proceeded to use useState and useEffect in conjunction with onSnapshot. The typical way of doing this seems to use onSnapshot() with useState and useEffect in the component, **OR** to use it in a custom hook. I rewrote my code to the following and it works as expected:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

/*
useComments is a custom React Hook.

Below is taken from the react website: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html
To share stateful logic between two or more JavaScript functions, we extract it to a third function. Both components and Hooks are functions, so this works for them too!
A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and that may call other Hooks.
*/

// -- returns an array of comments for a given taskId
// -- using the prefix of 'use' in front of the function name is important to identify it as a custom hook
export default function useComments(taskId) {
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const commentsRef = firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('tasks')
            .doc(taskId)
            .collection('comments') // comments is a subcollection of each task document
        const unsubscribe = commentsRef.onSnapshot(
            (snapshot) => {
                const commentsArray = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data(),
                }))
                setComments(commentsArray)
            },
            (error) => {
                throw new Error('Error: ' + error.message)
            }
        )
        return () => unsubscribe()
        // -- the return function activates when the componentWillUnmount, which is to clean up (unsubscribe) to the onSnapshot listener
    }, [])

    return comments // -- an array of comment objects with all the key value pairs, including the doc id. The doc.id will be used as the element's unique key when rendering the React component
}
```

I have been focusing on this issue in the React and Firestore ecosystem. I am not sure how to achieve the same effect if i was not using React (i.e. plain vanilla js). Maybe returning the snapshot result inside the next() function inside onSnapshot() is sufficient (as @kamillamagna suggested)